# iif and zero as a false result

Tags: ms-access, addition, zero, iif

I am working on an Access Database that will allow a manager to perform some validation on form entries of our staff.  The general Idea is that this query will compare the staff members answer against the managers answer and depending on the difference it will deduct points from a total possible of 100. This same `iif` is performed 21 times for each condition of the form.

For some reason when I run this query the 0 in the `iif` false category is not populating in my records and that is making my math function to also not populate. Here is the `iif`:

```
IIf([F1]="2",IIf([F2]<>[F1],-4.76,IIf([F1]="3",IIf([F2]<>[F1],-1,0))))
```

This works if the conditions are true but not if all conditions are false.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the problem a little longer this was the solution.

```
IIf([F1]="2",IIf([F2]<>[F1],-4.76,IIf([F1]="3",IIf([F2]<>[F1],-1))),0)
```